# Tecnicismo o neologismo para historias coetáneas

Tags: neologismos

Puede que la respuesta venga en el título, pero pongamos el contexto. Leyendo un artículo acerca de [secuela](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secuela_(arte)), vi un término que me produjo algo de risa y otro poco de extrañeza. Con la palabra *Medicuela* se hace referencia a una historia que se desarrolla durante los sucesos de otra obra terminada. A mí la palabra me sonó a sinónimo de [medicucha](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ol98h5T) (el final -uelo o -uela tiene su sonido despectivo) y si bien me parece que una frase como *historia contemporánea* o *historia coetánea* podrían describir la nueva obra, ¿Se puede tomar algún tecnicismo o neologismo que cubra la definición dada?

Comment: Por "tomar algún tecnicismo o neologismo" preguntas qué otra descripción de medicuela se pueda crear o componer en una frase para  que suene más comprensible ¿verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Puesto a crear (jugar) con neologismos descriptivos de *medicuela* (disparado por tu sugerencia de *historia coetanea*) se me ocurren

> ***inter-historia*** 
>   /
>   historia anidada
>   /
>   obra intersticial

también podría nombrarse como

> sucesos [eventos] coetáneos

(y otras combinaciones así)